Не видно старые непрочитанные сообщения


да, у меня тоже самое где-то дней 10 (недавно, был ru.SO недоступен, вот с того времени этот сбой пошел) => обновляешь страницу выходит //использую Chrome

"Перейти к списку всех входящих"

@Dev18, про обновление страницы вообще не понял. Не уверен, что это сбой, думаю, просто в топ не попадают...

@aepot, тогда попадёшь во все входящие - и? Даже если второй раз нажать, то попадёшь на страницу с пейджингом по уведомлениям, но там нет фильтра - мне что, постранично пролистывать и искать?

Qwertiy, https://i.sstatic.net/MB5Hejgp.png у меня это началось с этого дня, НЕ ВСЕГДА, но переодически висит красная цифра...потом обновляю страницу, и тогда вижу жирным шрифтом непрочитанное, но у меня обычно не 10-15, а 2-3, поэтому в выпадающем списке они появляются. А еще бывает, но это и раньше было иногда. Кликаешь на уведомление, но оно все равно не уходит...красная цифра висит (там именно надо нажать на само уведомление, чтоб ушло, - это понятно, но именно, что не уходит, пока пару раз страницу не обновишь...)

Не только для старых для меня актуально. То есть:висит цифра... Нажимаешь ничего нового нету, обновляешь страницу (иногда не раз) выходит жирным сообщение...

@Dev18, ну это какая-то другая проблема...

@Dev18, кстати, а в твоём случае там кнопочка "обновить уведомления" не появляется?

Ничего не появляется, как будто вообще нет ничего-открыл обычный список обычным шрифтом, а цифра висит будто есть не прочитанное... Потом пару раз клик клик обновил страницу опять открываю, и уже появляется жирным шрифтом сообщение не прочитанное. Морока этот баг записать, так бы открыла вопрос. Пока что не так часто вроде, и сравнительно недавно началось, но если получится во время записать процесс, потом собрать в вопрос информацию, тогда отпишусь

Хотя...  вы говорите, что не тот же баг, но я почему то к этому же сценарию отношу. Это уведомление-пропавшие сообщения (старые новые какая разница по сути) так что, если этот дефект решат, то и это решится думаю

@Dev18, https://i.sstatic.net/Z46kb0Wm.png & https://i.sstatic.net/bZLdLZcU.png.

Reported on Meta Stack Exchange: Filtering unread inbox notifications only displays items that are unread in the summary list and not all unread items
